# Core Data - How often to fetch objects?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest

So I do alot of fetching of my objects. At startup for instance I set an unread count for the badge on a tab. To get this unread count I need to fetch my datamodel objects to see which objects have the flag unread. So there we have a fetch. Then right after that method I do another fetch of all my datamodel objects to do something else. And then on the view controller I need to display my datamodel objects so I do another fetch there and so on.

So there are alot of calls like this : `NSArray *dataModelObjects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];`

This seems kind of redundant to me? Since I will be working alot with my datamodel objects can I not just fetch them once in the application and access them through an instance variable whenever I need to access them? But I always want to have up-to-date data. So there can be added and/or deleted datamodel objects.

Am I making any sense on what I want to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On of the concepts and benefits of Core Data is that you don't need to access the database every time you need an object - that's why `NSManagedObjectContext` was created - it stores those objects, retrieved from the database, so if you will try to get the object you've already get fromt the database, it wil be really fast.

And every change in those objects, made in the `NSManagedObjectContext` are automaticly brought to you.

But if you had some changes in the database, they may not be reflected in the `NSManagedObjectContext`, so you'll have to refresh them. You can read about keeping objects up-to-date [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-208900).

Comment: So is my approach correct here? Is it best practice to do a fetch request every time you want to work with your objects?

Comment: Really, i don't feel like that - if the object is the same, you should just store it as a variable, like MyNsManagedObjectClass *object = [[moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]lastObject];
But if you change your request, and you make it every time you change it - that's OK

Comment: Well these objects are very dynamic. So they will be created and deleted and modified. So then I suppose it is best to do my approach. That every time I need to work with my objects I make a new fetch request?

Comment: Are they chnaged in the ame app?Not in the database?If not, than don't fo that - you don't need it.

Comment: Users that are using my app will create/modify/delete objects.